# how to sort values in plotly px.violin

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-python, violin-plot

guys!

i am plotting some distributions across different states using `px.violin` and i want to order the stated based on distribution: right now you can see that florida with the biggest variance and higher values is in the middle, while i want it on the first left position and then descending, so second should be colorado, third probably louisiana etc.

[image]

i've been trying to do that with the help of `natsort` package, doing

```
category_orders = {'state': natsorted(true_percentile_df['price per acre_x'].unique())}
```

but that does not seem to be working. any ideas?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use groupBy and sort by var like I've done here or define a custom order.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["jojo", 3], ["marcel", 4], ["jojo", 20], ["jojo", 0.1], ["marcel", 9], ["pierre", 0.9], ["pierre", 0.8], ["pierre", 0.8]], columns=["Name", "Value"])

px.violin(df,
         x="Name",
         y="Value",
         points = "all",
         category_orders={"Name": df.groupby("Name").var().sort_values('Value',ascending=False).index.to_list()})
```

[image: my results]

Hope it'll help.

Comment: yeah, thank you so much! your way of groupping it did exactly what i wanted with the plot!